# Discord bot doesn't show my server avatar

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net

I have 2 commands in my discord bot one to get the command authors avatar and one to get the guild avatar

```
[SlashCommand("download", "get the guild pfp")]
        public async Task guildicon()
             var userId = Context.User.Id;
            var guildIcon = Context.Guild.IconUrl;
            await RespondAsync($"<@{userId}> Download **=>** {guildIcon}");
```

I tried to do get the guild avatar the same way I did my other command but the bot isn't showing the guild iconurl. The only response I get from the bot is a blank message

Comment: Is the whole message of the bot blank? Or do you get the `userId`? Or is the whole interaction failing?

Comment: the bot mentions the command authors username and "download" and then theres no link to the avatar.

Comment: Are you sure that your guild has a custom icon? The default icon will return null/empty string.

Comment: Oh I didnt have a server pic, so thats why! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the comments, the Discord API doesn't return the default Avatar. That's why `avatar` is nullable as you can see [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object). So you need to be sure that your guild has an custom Avatar set.